# Defining Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. I'm reading the section where he is defining matrix multiplication:
[image]

And I'm kind of confused with all the notation. Would someone be willing to help me through it? Any help/hints appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What does $\mathcal M$ denote here?

Comment: Sums play a crucial role in matrix calculations. Do you understand the sums and how the last sum defines a matrix product ?

Comment: @YiFan its the matrix of a linear map. So for example, $M(S)=A$. A is the matrix of S with respect to the bases of V and W

Comment: If you are confused, then try to deal with the simpler cases, like $n = 3, m = 2, p = 3$.

Comment: @Peter I think understand the last sum. Its saying $M(ST)$'s entries will be the rows of $A$ multiplied by columns of $C$. I'm confused on all the middle sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking that notation:
\begin{align}(S\circ T)(u_k) &= S(T(u_k)) = S(\sum_{r=1}^n C_{r,k}v_r)\tag{1}\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n C_{r,k}S(v_r)\tag{2}\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n C_{r,k}\sum_{j=1}^m A_{j,r}w_j\tag{3}\\
(S\circ T)(u_k) &= \sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{r=1}^n A_{j,r}C_{r,k}\right)w_j\tag{4}\end{align}
I tweaked a bit there, using functional notation for the linear operators rather than plain "multiplication". The meaning, though, is all the same.
In line 1, we write out $T(u_k)$ in terms of its known matrix. That's really just the definition of the matrix $C$ there.
Moving to line 2, we move $S$ inside the sum by linearity. Since it's a linear map, $S$ of a linear combination of vectors is that linear combination of $S$ of those vectors.
Moving to line 3, we write out the values of $S(v_r)$ in terms of the matrix $A$ of $S$ - the same thing we did in line 1.
Moving to line 4, we switch the order of summation. In the old order, we had to keep all of the terms with $j$ in them in the inner sum, while in the new order it's the terms with $r$ in them that have to be on the inside and the term $w_j$ can be brought to the outer sum.
Now, at the end, we have $(S\circ T)(u_k)$ written as a sum over $j$ of some coefficients times $w_j$. Those coefficients $B_{j,k}=\sum_{r=1}^n A_{j,r}C_{r,k}$ will then be the entries of the matrix of $S\circ T$, and we use this pattern to define matrix multiplication.

Comment: wow thank you so much. That's a really clear explanation. I never really knew why matrix multiplication is defined as such. Makes sense now